# Derivative of a Derivative in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I am trying to do some calculations in python and now need to find the derivative of the a function, that I have derived prior and is now called derivative(x(t), t):

```
t = sp.symbols('t')
x = sp.symbols('x')
B = sp.symbols('B')
C = sp.symbols('C')
x = sp.Function('x')(t)

Lx = B * sp.diff(x,t) * C
```

Because the derivative of x is called `Derivative(x(t),t)` by SymPy,the function Lx is equal to `B*Derivative(x(t),t)*C` and the derivative of our function must be called the following:

```
ELx = sp.diff(Lx,Derivative(x(t),t))
```

But I allways get an error message:
`NameError: name 'Derivative' is not defined` what should I do.

I mean I can define the Derived function with antoher varibale, but the logic and cleaner way looks like this.

Comment: Have you tried `sp.Derivative(x(t),t)`?

Comment: Did you define or import `Derivative`?  Even though you are using `sympy` you are still working in python.

Comment: When you say you want a derivative you must clearly indicate *with respect to what", e.g. the derivative of y wrt x. You say "I need to find the derivative of a function" but you don't say with respect to what.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Derivative() without that being defined. According to the documentation of sympy the correct way to calculate a derivative is `sp.diff()`.

The following code should do what you're trying to achieve:

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t')
x = sp.Function('x')(t)
B = sp.symbols('B')
C = sp.symbols('C')

Lx = B * sp.diff(x,t) * C

# Take the derivative of Lx with respect to x(t)
ELx = sp.diff(Lx, x)
```

References:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/calculus.html

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do. The result of sp.diff(Lx, t) is B*Derivative(x(t),t)*C. But how do I derive for the Derivative(x((t),t)